# Laravel: How to use where clause in many to many relation

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many, has-and-belongs-to-many

How i can use where clause in many to many relation ship

Table: Users

```
   id - name - email
```

Table: Shiftings

```
   id - name
```

Table: shifting_user

```
   id - user_id - shifting_id
```

User Model:

```
public function shiftings()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\shifting');
}
```

in controller im using below custom query

```
public function index()
{
    return $user = DB::select('select * from shifting_user
    where user_id in (select id from users)' );
}
```

how i can convert this to laravel standard/equloent query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup their relationships first.

In your Shifting model:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

In your User model:

```
public function shiftings ()
{
     return $this->belongsToMany(Shifting::class);
}
```

Then you can get all shiftings including it's users associated with by simply doing an eager loading

```
$shiftings = Shifting::with('users')->get();
dd($shiftings);
```